# Embedded MySQL for Java

Tags: java, mysql, embed

I am looking for embedded MySQL for Java. I looked at answers for "[Create embedded mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379748/create-embedded-mysql-database)"
and found [`libmysqld`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/libmysqld.html) but it is for C++, as MySQL itself of course is written in C/C++.
Could not find better for MySQL per se.

Recalling about MariaDB, I quickly found https://github.com/vorburger/MariaDB4j but I am still raising question. Is there better solution for standalone app (that is only one local connection, we never can access that db)

UPDATE: There is no much I know. We should have embed all into one Java executable, but for the developers it should be the same as the MySQL on central server where mySQL native SQL calls are used. So having the same DB for main server and standalone app is supposed to save time developing against different DBs.

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Is SQLite not appropriate?

Comment: I guess SQLite will require checking/rewriting all SQL queries.